# Why is there a logical error if (arr.length == 0) {return Integer.MAX_VALUE;} is placed where it is?

Tags: java, recursion

I ran my code with if(arr.length == 0){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;} at the beginning of the method. However, is there a logic error regarding where if(arr.length == 0){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE; is placed?

```
import java.util.*;

class RecursiveMethods{

   public static int smallest(int[] arr){ // if size of array is 0, return max value
      // The next 4 lines are the changes I have made.
      if Math.min(arr[0],smallest(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,1,arr.length)));
   } // Return minimum of first element and ans obtained by subarray
   else { if(arr.length == 0){
      return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   }

   public static int smallest(int[][] arr){
      if(arr.length==0){
         return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      }
      return Math.min(smallest(arr[0]),smallest(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,1,arr.length)));
   }

   public static String repeat(String s, int n){ // n=0, return empty string
      if(n==0)return "";
      return s+repeat(s,n-1);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(smallest(new int[]{2,4,3,89,0,-9}));
      System.out.println(smallest(new int[][]{{1,2,3,4,1,0},{0,-8,-90}}));
      System.out.println(repeat("Hello",3));
   }
}
```

Comment: First of all, do fix all typos and compile time errors! This is not `Java`

Comment: Would you please point out the typos and compile time errors? Thanks

Comment: `if Math.min(arr[0],smallest(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr,1,arr.length)));` - this is not correct `Java` syntax

Comment: `else { if(arr.length == 0){` makes no sense

Comment: @JSW Rather than asking people to tell you what compile errors your code has, why don't you run it through a compiler?

Comment: @khelwood, I did. It did not come up in the compiler.

Comment: @JSW If you are really claiming that you ran _this code_ through a Java compiler without any errors, there is no way that is true, and you should go and figure out what part of that are doing wrong.

Comment: [Just in case, here is a compilation attempt](https://hasteb.in/eyiquyog.java)

Answer (score 1):

**No, this is not a logical error.** You're correct because you use `Math.min()` and for corner case, you can use smth that you can treat as a marker. So, `Math.min(arr[i], Integer.MAX_VALUE)` will retrieve `arr[i]`.

---

Additionally, I recommend you to pay attention to the performance of your methods. It's better not to make a copy of array on each recursion and not use `String` concatenation:

```
class RecursiveMethods {

    public static int smallest(int[] arr) {
        return smallest(arr, 0);
    }

    private static int smallest(int[] arr, int i) {
        if (i >= arr.length)
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        return Math.min(arr[i], smallest(arr, i + 1));
    }

    public static String repeat(String s, int n) {
        return repeat(s, n, new StringBuilder(s.length() * n)).toString();
    }

    private static StringBuilder repeat(String s, int n, StringBuilder buf) {
        if (n <= 0)
            return buf;
        buf.append(s);
        return repeat(s, n - 1, buf);
    }

}
```